# How to bind enum into combobox inside data template

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, combobox, binding

I have an **enum** that I need to **bind into a ComboBox**. The ComboBox is located inside the **data template tag**. How can I bind the enum into the ComboBox?

This is the enum:

```
 public enum Status
{
    Enable,
    Disable
}
```

This is the xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cv:StatusToBooleanConverter x:Key="statusToBooleanConverter"/>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enum:Status"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
     <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
     Path=DataContext.Statusstring}" x:Name="cbProductionLineStatus" 
     FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </StackPanel>    
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is the viewmodel code:

```
public List<Status> status;

    public List<Status> Statusstring
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (List<Status> iColor in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status)))
            {
                status =  iColor;
            }

            return status;
        }
    }
```

I tried implementing the Find ancestor method half way and got stucked.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                Path=?}" SelectedValue="{Binding ProductionLineStatus,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="ProductionLineStatus" DisplayMemberPath="ProductionLineStatus" x:Name="cbProductionLineStatus" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

I am trying to populate the enum status into my combobox but it is failing. However, now I am trying to implement as the solution stated by Steven but still its not working.

Comment: `Enums` can be converted into `int`, and an `int` can be stored in an combobox. 
Remember that `Enums` are usually preferred for readability on the code behind. and not to make their names an actual part of the program on the front end.

Comment: @Steven kindly view my question again. the problem here is binding the status to the combobox. If i have the combobox outside of the data template i am able to bind it successfully.

Comment: Can you reach dataFromEnum from datatemplate? assuming, for ie. that it's  a string array?

Comment: The ItemsSource is exaclty the same. The DataTemplate should also be defined as a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I able to solve this problem by implementing view model like this:

```
public Status status = Status.Enable;

    public List<string> Statusstring {
        get
        {
            return System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status)).ToList();

        }

    }
```

This is my xaml:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                Path=DataContext.Statusstring}" SelectedValue="{Binding ProductionLineStatus, Converter={StaticResource statusToBooleanConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="cbProductionLineStatus" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="16" Foreground="MidnightBlue" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have solved it by writing a property, and using that property in the Combobox:

Something similair like this:

```
public Status status = Status.Enable;

public string Statusstring
{
    get
    {
        if (status == Status.Enable)
            return "Enable";
        else
            return "Disable";
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get a sort or error message? The way how I define my datasource is different than yours. With just using `datasource="Statusstring" `, but I think that's because I'm using ASP.NET, instead of wpf.

Comment: Actually, there is no error messages being shown, but when I tried your method, its only displaying Enable as the status in all the rows, even I have few rows status which is Disable. Yes I am using wpf.

Comment: Well, looks like you've already managed to solve it yourself, which is good. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to implement the view model as answered by anonymous_apple. Then in the combo box you could further have a data template that contains a TextBlock. And in the Textblock you'd set the Text as so: Text="{Binding }".

^^This solved my issue, it should solve yours as well..